# Is there any way to update/replace whole document of mongoDB from java using mongoDB morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, web-services, morphia

I need to replace a whole existing document of mongodb from java instead of setting every field.Is there any way? I am using mongo morphia.

Right now i am setting fields one by one ,following is code :

```
DBObject searchObject =new BasicDBObject();

searchObject.put("procId", procId);

final UpdateOperations<Timesheet> updateOperations = ds.createUpdateOperations(Timesheet.class)

.set("wheelInTime", timesheet.getWheelInTime())

.set("wheelOutTime", timesheet.getWheelOutTime())

.set("tableOnTime", timesheet.getTableOnTime())

.set("tableOffTime", timesheet.getTableOffTime())

final UpdateResults results = ds.updateFirst(findQuery,updateOperations);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can 'overwrite' any entry in a MongoDB collection but simply creating a new DbObject with the same _id field and saving it to the database. So just set the fields in your object as you would any Java object and use myCollection.save(obj)

Answer (score 0):

Just save the object and it will overwrite the document with the same @id. This can be done with one line of code:

```
dao.save(timesheet);
```

More complete example code of the usage of the Morphia DAO:

```
class Dao extends BasicDAO<TimeSheet, String> {
  Dao(Datastore ds) {
    super(TimeSheet.class, ds);
  }
}

Datastore ds = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, DB_NAME);
Dao dao = new Dao(ds);

dao.save(timesheet);
```